# Calendar object millisecond in Java NumberFormatException

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

Am using calendar object to get the millisecond

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
```

But in some rare cases its returning invalid long millisecond.

Eg : .4201442014EE44

Its returning with floating point. Why is it so? Because am converting this millisecond to some date format. During conversion its throwing "NumberFormatException". As am doing SimpleDateFormat's format(millisecond).

Exception :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".4201442014EE44"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
at java.text.DigitList.getDouble(DigitList.java:168)
at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:1321)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1794)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1455)
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:355)
```

Comment: Please try `System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: Could you post the code? I guess there's something wrong between lines

Comment: Since Calendar.getTimeInMillis() doesn't return a String, your exception originates elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat.format(Object)` can format `Date` and `Number` instances. The number passed will be *converted to a long*, which is then interpreted as milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0000.

Passing anything else will cause an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date`.

Some examples:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd. MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
format.format(new Date());
format.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

With Calendar:

```
format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```

And arbitrary numbers:

```
format.format((double) System.currentTimeMillis());
format.format(BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```